Error: The Angular Webpack loader requires the AngularWebpackPlugin
Error: The Angular Webpack loader requires the AngularWebpackPlugin.
while making build for production i am getting this error while using webpack in angular 17
i was expecting a sucessful production build but got this error Error: The Angular Webpack loader requires the AngularWebpackPlugin.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see how to ask. Your question lacks any context. Have you created a new app, and if yes what did you do before it stopped working? Or did you update an existing app? Does the dev server work? What is the full error message? Can you create a minimal reproduction? Are you using the Angular CLI ng build command, or are you using a custom webpack build (in this case you will need to add more details about your custom build)?
